# Baofeng radio allowed in Australia?

Tags: legal, baofeng, australia

I am migrating to Australia, and want to find out whether I can carry my Baofeng UV82 HX / HP model there. The model has CE, FCC, ROHS compliance, and a black 'Tick' mark next to these three. 
If the same model is sold in Australia, I believe I can carry it too?

Comment: A friend of mine has ordered severa stock standard UV-5R's and they all went through Australian customs just fine. I have heard however that in order to speed up the procedure through customs some suppliers put a sticker over the battery saying it's a Li-Ion instead of Li-Po.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from a Google search of "Baofeng UV82 Australia" that the UV82 is sold there.  It's possible that there is a different firmware version for Australia, perhaps to restrict the power level or to keep users out of certain frequencies, but that seems unlikely to me.  Personally I would bring it; there's a small chance that it might be confiscated by Customs, but surely you could afford to buy another if that were to happen.

Answer (score 1):

When Migrating from one country to another, regardless of countries, it is a good idea to contact customs in both countries to ensure that you declare your equipment, and get information about the specifics of import/export details, forms, and procedures.

You don't want any surprises on the day itself.